# Valgrind invalid read/write when appending a character to a C string

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

I'm trying to parse through a string (size ranging from an article to a whole book), and build a temporary linked list to store each individual words, separated by any whitespace characters. I wrote my own `charAppend()` function since I don't think I can use `strcat()` and pass in `char* str` and `char c` as arguments. Eventually my goal is to organize this linked list of words into a hash table, and when I tried to output the hash table content in the format of `<word>:<number of occurrences>` with `printf` I got a seg fault. The arguments to `printf` seem to be ok on gdb, but when I ran valgrind I got a lot of `Invalid write of size 1` and `Invalid read of size 1` in my `charAppend()` function. I don't understand what's going on here since stepping through using gdb didn't give me much info.

my `charAppend()` function:

```
//str is my current word, and c is the character I'm trying to append 
char* charAppend(char* str, char c) { 
    int length = 0;
    if (str != NULL) {
        length = strlen(str);
        str[length] = c;
        str = realloc(str, length+1);
        str[length+1] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        str = malloc(2); //1 for c, 1 for \0
        str[0] = c;
        str[1] = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}
```

And here are some of the error messages:

line 191 is `str[length+1] = '\0';`

```
% valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes test_wc wc-small.txt
==21794== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21794== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21794== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21794== Command: test_wc wc-small.txt
==21794== 
==21794== Invalid write of size 1
==21794==    at 0x109528: charAppend (wc.c:191)
==21794==    by 0x108EB5: wc_init (wc.c:47)
==21794==    by 0x108DAB: main (test_wc.c:47)
==21794==  Address 0x54db1e2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==21794==    at 0x4C2DDCF: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==21794==    by 0x109513: charAppend (wc.c:190)
==21794==    by 0x108EB5: wc_init (wc.c:47)
==21794==    by 0x108DAB: main (test_wc.c:47)
==21794== 
==21794== Invalid read of size 1
==21794==    at 0x4C2EDB4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==21794==    by 0x1094E5: charAppend (wc.c:188)
==21794==    by 0x108EB5: wc_init (wc.c:47)
==21794==    by 0x108DAB: main (test_wc.c:47)
==21794==  Address 0x54db1e2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==21794==    at 0x4C2DDCF: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==21794==    by 0x109513: charAppend (wc.c:190)
==21794==    by 0x108EB5: wc_init (wc.c:47)
==21794==    by 0x108DAB: main (test_wc.c:47)
```

There are at least 10 more of such error messages, some `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` as a result of line 190, `str = realloc(str, length+1);` and a few that might be a consequence of these when I'm trying to print the hash table content, which I don't even understand.

```
==21794== Invalid read of size 8
==21794==    at 0x1092CE: wc_output (wc.c:124)
==21794==    by 0x108DD1: main (test_wc.c:51)
==21794==  Address 0xffefffe20 is on thread 1's stack
==21794==  1680 bytes below stack pointer
==21794== 
==21794== Invalid read of size 8
==21794==    at 0x1092EA: wc_output (wc.c:125)
==21794==    by 0x108DD1: main (test_wc.c:51)
==21794==  Address 0xffefffe20 is on thread 1's stack
==21794==  1680 bytes below stack pointer
```

My guess is that I don't have a correct understanding of how C strings (especially modifying them) work (It's been 2 years since I took an intro level C course), but any help on what went or might be wrong, and suggestions on how to debug these would be appreciated!

I can post more code if that helps, but I think `charAppend()` is the primary suspect.

Comment: `realloc(str, length+1);` is off by one. An array of size `length+1` has no index `length+1`.

Comment: ^as @tkausl said: you allocate *2* characters in the `malloc` branch yet you store a string of length 1. You're never resizing your allocation. Furthermore, you should modify your code - keep track of the allocated buffer and allocate with geometric not arithmetic increase (multiply size by 2 say), otherwise you're going to have really slow code.

Comment: If a book has 500 000 characters say, your code would expand the array 500000 times and every time it needs to reallocate, it will copy approximately half the characters. Let's say realloc can expand in 7 cases out of 8, so it needs to only copy 62500 times the 250000 - you're needlessly copying 15 gigabytes of stuff in memory.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I thought about that, but since I'm parsing through A LOT of characters would there be a problem with wasting space if I allocate geometrically, and only append 1 character each time?

Comment: @gouhaha you'd keep track of the current allocation. You would want to pass the length of the allocation as a pointer to `size_t`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh about that, every time I encounter a whitespace character, I would copy this word to a linked list and free it.

Comment: ah ok then :D then it doesn't matter. Though you'd want to keep an ever expanding buffer large enough to store the longest word so far - easier that way :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Is the buffer which has the size of longest word so far going to be faster than my `char* currentWord`, which gets passed into `charAppend()` and when finished, `free(currentWord); currentWord = NULL`? There is a 30 sec time limit on the tester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in this part:

```
    length = strlen(str);
    str[length] = c;
    str = realloc(str, length+1);
    str[length+1] = '\0';
```

1) `strlen` does **not** give you the amount of memory allocated. It gives the amount **minus 1**. This is because `strlen` does not include the string termination. So your `realloc` is wrong.

2) Never `realloc` directly into the target pointer. `realloc` may return NULL

So try like:

```
    length = strlen(str);
    char * tmp = realloc(str, length+2); // note +2
    if (tmp == NULL) exit(1);            // bad error
    str = tmp;
    str[length] = c;
    str[length+1] = '\0';
```